# One factor level becomes NA when I reorder them, why is this?

Tags: r

I have the following data:

```
> dataAvg
# A tibble: 20 x 3
# Groups:   Date [5]
   Date  Rate   meanNitrogen
   <fct> <fct>         <dbl>
 1 7.16  Rate 1         1.36
 2 7.16  Rate 2         1.29
 3 7.16  Rate 3         1.40
 4 7.16  Rate 4         1.11
 5 7.22  Rate 1         1.41
 6 7.22  Rate 2         1.34
 7 7.22  Rate 3         1.62
 8 7.22  Rate 4         1.08
 9 7.29  Rate 1         1.38
10 7.29  Rate 2         1.39
11 7.29  Rate 3         1.51
12 7.29  Rate 4         1.14
13 7.8   Rate 1         1.34
14 7.8   Rate 2         1.38
15 7.8   Rate 3         1.38
16 7.8   Rate 4         1.08
17 8.05  Rate 1         1.39
18 8.05  Rate 2         1.35
19 8.05  Rate 3         1.42
20 8.05  Rate 4         1.02
```

And I am trying to make the following ggplot:

```
ggplot(dataAvg, aes(x=Date, y=meanNitrogen, group=Rate)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
  facet_wrap(.~Rate)
```

However, the date (a factor) is read alphabetically and not chronologically. To change this, I added the following line of code:

```
dataAvg$Date <- factor(dataAvg$Date,levels(dataAvg$Date)[c(4,1,2,3,5)])
```

Here is the output before changing the order:

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L), .Label = c("7.1", "7.16", "7.22", "7.29", "7.8", "8.05", 
"8.18"), class = "factor"), Rate = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("Rate 1", "Rate 2", "Rate 3", "Rate 4"
), class = "factor"), meanNitrogen = c(4.955, 5.005, 5.1075, 
4.01, 6.3325, 5.485, 6.1825, 4.2275, 5.195, 4.825, 5.325, 3.765, 
5.0225, 4.93, 5.3925, 3.82, 5.2225, 5.34, 5.2025, 4.0225, 4.43, 
4.3775, 4.725, 3.7025)), row.names = c(NA, -24L), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), groups = structure(list(Date = structure(1:6, .Label = c("7.1", 
"7.16", "7.22", "7.29", "7.8", "8.05", "8.18"), class = "factor"), 
    .rows = list(1:4, 5:8, 9:12, 13:16, 17:20, 21:24)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE))
```

and here is the output after:

```
 > dput(dataAvg)
structure(list(Date = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L), .Label = c("7.1", "7.8", "7.16", "7.22", "7.29", "8.05"), class = "factor"), 
    Rate = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
    3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("Rate 1", 
    "Rate 2", "Rate 3", "Rate 4"), class = "factor"), meanNitrogen = c(4.955, 
    5.005, 5.1075, 4.01, 6.3325, 5.485, 6.1825, 4.2275, 5.195, 
    4.825, 5.325, 3.765, 5.0225, 4.93, 5.3925, 3.82, 5.2225, 
    5.34, 5.2025, 4.0225, 4.43, 4.3775, 4.725, 3.7025)), row.names = c(NA, 
-24L), groups = structure(list(Date = structure(1:6, .Label = c("7.1", 
"7.16", "7.22", "7.29", "7.8", "8.05", "8.18"), class = "factor"), 
    .rows = list(1:4, 5:8, 9:12, 13:16, 17:20, 21:24)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

In other scenarios, this has solved this issue, however, here I lose the "8.05" date in the ggplot. The date is replaced with an "NA" value. I could not find a solution when searching on stackoverflow or elsewhere. Any help for getting rid of the NA would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It will be difficult to help without a reproducible example. Can you edit your question to include the output of `dput()`?

Comment: Might be better to convert `Date` to type date, by first mutating to add a year.

Comment: @sjp thanks for the comment. Did I add the right information? Just updated my post

Comment: Yes like @neilfws says could make them dates:
`lubridate::ymd(paste0("00.", as.character(tmp)))`

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to make a couple of suggestions which do not answer your question as written, but I think might improve the data visualisation. See if you agree.

1. If you have dates, then use `date` as the variable type
2. Plot lines (or points) instead of columns

Assuming the year of your dates is 2020 and the current format is `month.day`, you can convert them using `dplyr::mutate`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

dataAvg %>% 
  mutate(newDate = as.Date(paste0(Date, ".2020"), "%m.%d.%Y")) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(newDate, meanNitrogen)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  facet_wrap(~Rate)
```

Result:

[image]

**EDIT:** as your focus is comparison by Rate for a given date, a better line graph would color by Rate instead of using facets.

```
dataAvg %>% 
  mutate(newDate = as.Date(paste0(Date, ".2020"), "%m.%d.%Y")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(newDate, meanNitrogen)) + 
  geom_line(aes(color = Rate))
```

[image]

Or if you think columns is clearer:

```
dataAvg %>% 
  mutate(newDate = as.Date(paste0(Date, ".2020"), "%m.%d.%Y")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(newDate, meanNitrogen)) + 
  geom_col(aes(fill = Rate), position = position_dodge())
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the thoughtful response! I believe that keeping the data as a bar graph is actually better in my specific situation. The focus of this group of subplots is to compare the results of each treatment on each collection date to each other. For example, I want the reader to be able to compare all trts' responses on 7/8 to each other. The change over time for a trt by itself is not actually the focus, although I see why you would assume that. Changing the plot this way ends up making it harder to make the comparisons that I'd like (I think). What are your thoughts on this?

Comment: In that case, I would color the lines by Rate, instead of using facets. I'll edit the answer to show that.

Comment: Added an example with bars too.

Answer (score 0):

### You're dropping factor levels

When you subset `levels(avgData$Date)`, you subset by manually arranging values between 1 and 5. `avgData$Date` has seven levels, so the levels you exclude (namely, the sixth and seveth levels) are dropped from the vector.

You need to do something like:

`dataAvg$Date <- factor(dataAvg$Date,levels(dataAvg$Date)[c(4,1,2,3,5,6,7)])`

Only in whatever order it is that you want.

#### Additional advice

As others have said, your best bet would be to use a Date object, rather than a factor. If you want/need to use factors, consider using functions from the `forcats` package which are less likely to drop factors, such as `forcats::relevel()` (analagous to what you're currently doing) or `forcats::reorder()` (run the levels through a function and reorder based on the output).

Comment: Thanks for the response! Would you mind explaining a little more for me, as this left me a little confused. While the original dataset had 7 levels of the date factor, the dataAvg only has data for 5 of them (there were not collections for this type of the other 2 dates). Because of this, there's only 5 levels being expressed in the plot. You can see in my first posted dataAvg table that there's only 5 levels. Why are all 7 still relevant? And how do I see how to order them if all 7 aren't in the plot? Thanks again!

Comment: Oh yes I see. I ran your reprex (the code under 'Here is the output before changing the order:') and got a factor with 7 levels. If your data is the tibble displayed in the question, I'm not sure what's happening.

Comment: Do you lose the '8.05' level in the tibble, or just in the plot? If it's the latter, we'll need to see your ggplot code

Comment: Yeah, it's a pretty strange issue. After I reorder the date factor, I'm actually losing it in the tibble as well as the plot. Any idea why that might be?

Comment: You are dropping levels, somehow, by definition. It's happening in your reordering, so it's not a ggplot2 problem. Have you tried the `forcats` functions I suggested above? It might help you to know (if you don't already) that a factor is just a vector of integers which correspond to the indeces of its 'levels' attribute, which contains the character data.

Comment: As always, producing a minimal, reproducible example would help greatly. Presently I still can't reproduce your problem. Often the process of creating a minimal reprex simplifies the problem and makes the solution obvious. Check this article: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
`reprex::reprex(venue = "so")` is also very cool - just `Ctrl+C` your code (must be self contained), run the function and paste into S.O.